# Gratitude Denied

Tags: lateral-thinking

In a small kingdom, there once was a evil king. A dashing prince showed up one day… and immediately died to puzzles. Even more princes showed up, and it was practically a XP farm for the evil king. Why did they all show up? Because he was LOADED. He was *rolling* in cash. Everyone wanted to get adopted by him and be his heir. So, he set up a simple puzzle to weed out the unworthy. You had to landscape his perfectly square garden into a image of his face, which had a large, red birthmark. Unfortunately, he didn’t have any red, brown, purple, or organish-red flowers.

One day, two children arrived. They began working on the puzzle. When they asked why the king had no red flowers, he said “This is what happens when you buy flowers in bulk.” They tried painting the flowers, but the king screamed “NO! Can’t you hear the tulip *screaming* in agony? *NEVER paint my tulips.*”

*However, the children solved the puzzle. How?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They used

> Coloured stones and pebbles to create the image. Reminds me of a [story](https://www.worldclasslearning.com/akbar-birbal-stories/best-flowers.html)

Comment: How pleasant. :)